# Dealing with Dates and Summing up Rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the resulting table to be like the example Table I have provided, even though the only month provided was 5, I want the table to display all the 12 months even if the Amount was to be 0 for the other months.

I'm using this Query, Let me try and explain exactly what I want when it comes to the Amount. I want the amount column to contain the sum of every sale for the corresponding month.

```
Select   
    YEAR([Date]) as [Year],
    MONTH([Date]) as [Month],
    IsNull(SUM(Amount), 0) AS TotalSales
From Sales Left Outer Join Employee
On Employee.EmployeeID = Sales.EmployeeID
    Group By YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date])
    Order By YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date])
```

---

Employee Table,

```
+--+--+------+
|ID|  Name   |
+--+---------+
|1 |John Doe |
+--+---------+
|2 |Jane Doe |
+--+---------+
```

Sales Table,

```
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|ID|SaleID| Date    |Amount |Quantity|
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|1 |  1   |5-14-2014|300    |12      |
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|1 |  2   |5-16-2014|600    |4       |
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|2 |  3   |5-14-2014|452    |10      |
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
|2 |  4   |5-16-2014|356    |2       |
+--+------+---------+-------+--------+
```

What I want,

```
+--+---------+-----+------+--------+--------+
|ID|  Name   |Year |Month |Amount  |Quantity|
+--+---------+-----+------+--------+--------+
|1 |John Doe |2014 |5     |900     |16      |
+--+---------+-----+------+--------+--------+
|2 |Jane Doe |2014 |5     |808     |12      |
+--+---------+-----+------+--------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Select S.ID,E.Name,YEAR(MAX([Date])) as [Year],MONTH(MAX([Date])) as [Month],
      IsNull(SUM(Amount), 0) AS TotalSales,IsNull(SUM(Quantity), 0) AS TotalQuantity
From Sales S Left Join Employee E On E.ID = S.ID
Group By S.ID,E.Name,YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date])
Order By S.ID
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e034/3)**

*Output:*

---

```
+--+---------+-----+------+--------+--------+
|ID|  Name   |Year |Month |Amount  |Quantity|
+--+---------+-----+------+--------+--------+
|1 |John Doe |2014 |5     |900     |16      |
+--+---------+-----+------+--------+--------+
|2 |Jane Doe |2014 |5     |808     |12      |
+--+---------+-----+------+--------+--------+
```

**Update**

If you wanna display the months (1-12) even though that month would have an Amount of 0

Try This

```
;With Months (Month,MonthID) 
AS
(

    select 'January' as Month , 1 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'February' as Month , 2 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'March' as Month , 3 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'April' as Month , 4 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'May' as Month , 5 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'June' as Month , 6 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'July' as Month , 7 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'August' as Month , 8 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'September' as Month , 9 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'October' as Month , 10 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'November' as Month , 11 as MonthID
    UNION
    select 'December' as Month , 12 as MonthID

)

SELECT R.ID,R.Name,R.[Year],M.[MonthID],M.[Month],R.TotalSales,R.TotalQUANTITY FROM
Months M LEFT JOIN
(
Select S.ID,E.Name,YEAR([Date]) as [Year],MONTH([Date]) as [Month],
      IsNull(SUM(Amount), 0) AS TotalSales,IsNull(SUM(Quantity), 0) AS TotalQuantity
From Sales S Left Join Employee E On E.ID = S.ID
Left OUTER JOIN Months ON MonthID = MONTH([Date])
Group By S.ID,E.Name,YEAR([Date]), MONTH([Date])
) R ON R.Month = M.MonthID
Order By CASE WHEN R.ID IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 End,R.ID,M.MonthID
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7e034/33)**

Comment: Seems to be working :) But in regards to my other request, I'd like for the results to show all months even if they're not listed as a sale day.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide the sample output @Prosperity

Comment: Basically the same as your output but within the Month Column it would display the months (1-12) even though that month would have an Amount of 0

Comment: @Prosperity I have updated answer Please check and let me know

Comment: This is sort of what I'd like but it would display 1 - 12 for each Employee

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT e.ID,
       e.Name,
       YEAR(s.date)AS Year,
       MONTH(s.date)AS Month,
       sum(s.amount) AS Amount,
       sum(s.quantity) AS Quantity
FROM Employee e
LEFT JOIN Sales s ON e.id=s.id
GROUP BY e.ID,e.Name,year(s.date),month(s.date)
```

Comment: I've Tried this but it gives me an error because e.id and e.name need to be either an aggregated function or in the Group by

Comment: what you get error please mention here so i can help you

Comment: @Sadikhasan You have to include `e.name` for `Group by` Clause

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```
select ID,Name,yaer,monht,Amount,quantity from
(
select distinct Year(Date1) as yaer,Month(Date1) as monht,rn=ROW_NUMBER()over(order by Year(Date1)) from #emp
)x,
(
select a.ID,a.Name,sum(b.Amount) as Amount,sum(b.Quantity) as quantity,rn1=row_number()over(order by a.ID) from #sales a join #emp b on a.ID=b.ID
group by a.ID,a.Name
)y
where x.rn=y.rn1
```

## [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/19198)